# How to modify HTML in Oracle procedure

Tags: html, stored-procedures, html-email, oracle

I made procedure which sends email via job but result set (body part of procedure) is looking messy like this

```
Case id: 12345, 6789,8989898 Case name: name ;nameeeeeeeeeee Case Category: Email - post by post by post;Email - inbound/making fine and sending case;Email - Create date: today
```

And i would like to look like this

```
Case id: 12345, 6789,8989898
Case name: name ;nameeeeeeeeeee
Case Category: Email - post by post by post; Email - inbound/making fine and sending case; Email - Create date: today
```

So, i would like to create new line after record
My code is like this (part of my procedure).

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement for your procedure; the HTML that your procedure generates; and the expected HTML that you would like to generate. At the moment your question contains no code so it is difficult to see how we can advise you on something we cannot see (other than to say add `<br />` tags to the HTML).

Comment: You didn't mention how you generate the email, and how you view the email. Note that Outlook joins lines of pure text emails into the same line (like what you saw). If this is your case, you can use HTML email, or add 3 leading spaces to each line of your message.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what API you are using to send the email. Could be UTL_STMP, could be UTL_MAIL etc.

At the lowest level (UTL_SMTP) you really need to compose the HTML youself. A good example of that on AskTom

https://asktom.oracle.com/ords/asktom.search?tag=sending-html-using-utl-smtp

But I didnt include the content here, because a better option would be use the APEX_MAIL package that comes with APEX (free to install and use on any database), because then it is as easy as:

```
  apex_mail.send(
    p_to        => 'abc@efg.com',
    p_from      => 'noreply@blah.com',
    p_body      => 'plain text if you want it',
    p_body_html => 'your html if you prefer that',
    p_subj      => 'Your email subject line'
  );
```